# Perl Array values show in different line without using loop

Tags: perl

Could anyone tell me how could I print values of array in different rows without using loop?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my @a = ('Test1','Test2','Test3');
print "@a";# output like **Test1 Test2 Test3** but i want **Test2 in next line and Test3 next to next line**
```

Is it Possible?

Answer (score 8):

You can just do:

```
print join("\n", @ar);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can set $" variable

```
 $" = "\n";
```

It's probably better to do

```
{
     local $" = "\n";
     print "@ar";
}
```

EDIT:

according to the [camel book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596000278) :

$" (or the alternative $LIST_SEPERATOR) specifies the string to put between individual elements when an array is interpolated into a double-quoted string, this for the case you want to say:

```
print "@ar";
```

$, (or the alternative $OUTPUT_FIELD_SEPERATOR) specifies the string to put between individual elements when you want to print a list. It's initially empty. You can set $, for the case you want to say:

```
 print @ar;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `$,` special variable to be whatever you want to separate your list elements. This should do what you want:

```
$, = "\n";
my @a = ('Test1','Test2','Test3');
print @a;
```

Comment: that would only work with multiple elements passed to print (`print @a`) instead of a single string.

Answer (score 1):

use map function

print @array = map{"$_\n"} @a;